# PHP cURL upload speed

Tags: php, apache, curl, bandwidth

I made a script that uploads files to different servers using [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and the problem is that it eats all my upload bandwidth and my Apache server does not respond as I would like.

The call is made from the [PHP-CLI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/CLI) and can not use any Apache bandwidth, limiting bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CURLOPT_READFUNCTION option? Creating your own function for reading the data will allow you also to throttle the bandwidth.

Answer (score -2):

Apache doesn't have any bandwidth limits. It's your network's bandwidth limit. Consider **not to spam other sites**, and your Apache server would always respond quickly.

Comment: there are bandwith limiting mods like mod_bw